# Node.js Chat Application Cluster Server using Socket.IO

Tags: node.js

I have created the code like for chat application

The above code is working fine for single server but for cluster server it gives error
client not handshaken client should reconnect, socket.io in cluster

can you please anyone help me to workout for cluster server

Thanks.

### Edit: Code

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http'); 
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length; 
var sio = require('socket.io'); 
var server;

if (cluster.isMaster) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) { 
        cluster.fork();
    } cluster.on('online', function(worker) { 
        console.log('A worker with #' + worker.id); 
    }); 
    cluster.on('listening', function(worker, address) { 
        console.log('A worker is now connected to ' + address.address + ':' + address.port); 
    }); 
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) { 
        console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died'); 
    }); 
} else { 
    server = http.createServer(function(req, res) { 
        res.writeHead(200); res.end('hello world\n'); 
    }).listen(8000); 
    _socketServer(); 
} 
var _socketServer = function() { 
    io = sio.listen(server); 
    io.set("log level", 1); 
    io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) { });
});
```

Error: `client not handshaken client should reconnect, socket.io in cluster`

Comment: What have you attempted? Please trying posting some code so that people can understand easier where the problem lies

Comment: var cluster = require('cluster');
    var http = require('http');
    var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
    var sio = require('socket.io');
    var server;

Comment: if (cluster.isMaster) {


     for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
         cluster.fork();
     }

     cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
       console.log('A worker with #' + worker.id);
     });

     cluster.on('listening', function(worker, address) {
      console.log('A worker is now connected to ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
     });

  
      cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
      console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
       });
     }

Comment: else {
      server =  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end('hello world\n');
      }).listen(8000);

     _socketServer();
    }

    var _socketServer = function() {
     io = sio.listen(server);
     io.set("log level", 1);
  
      io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
     });
     });


I am getting error like this

**client not handshaken client should reconnect, socket.io in cluster**

Comment: well for one thing, you have a syntax error here: `var _socketServer = function() { ... });`  you have a trailing closing `);` on the last line that doesn't need to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using redis server in cluster and subscribe to events exposed by redis server. It is one of the solution to solve this problem.

Edit:
Some code sample/architecture/frameworks used and all other information would be very helpful

Code:

Hi Guys,

Actually i am trying to create a chat application using socket.io

For single server it is working fine but when i try creating using cluster server then its 
not working for me

Throws error : 
**client not handshaken client should reconnect, socket.io in cluster**
**web socket invalid**

These error are continuously arising in console

Can someone help me to proceed for cluster server for socket.IO

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var sio = require('socket.io');
var server;

 if (cluster.isMaster) {


 for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
     cluster.fork();
 }

 cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
   console.log('A worker with #' + worker.id);
 });

 cluster.on('listening', function(worker, address) {
  console.log('A worker is now connected to ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
 });


  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
  console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
   });
 }
else {
  server =  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);

 _socketServer();
}

var _socketServer = function() {
 io = sio.listen(server);
 io.set("log level", 1);

  io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
 });
 });
```

I am getting error like this

**client not handshaken client should reconnect, socket.io in cluster**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to store socket information for all workers:

```
var ClusterStore = require('strong-cluster-socket.io-store')(io);
io = require("socket.io").listen(server)
io.set({'store': new ClusterStore()});
```

Use npm to install module 'strong-cluster-socket.io-store'